# Changing my username field from CharField to ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been told that using `ForeignKey(User)` for a username field is recommended so I am trying to implement that now. But I am having trouble transitioning from my current Charfield() to a ForeignKey() field.

My code below shows how my current `CharField()` is being used to assist in an ajax call. It currently works by clicking on a username, which gets the HTML of that username clicked and then can .get() any profile by searching the `CharField()` like this `profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)`. By the way, the HTML from that username clicked is from another `Charfield()`, `author`, which is a field in my comment model for when someone makes a comment. So the ajax call opens up a small profile box with a few details of the user clicked. Here's my code:

**profile model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='AnonymousUser')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**js**

```
$('a.username').on('click', function() {

    var username = $(this).html();
    var url = "/raise_profile/";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {
            username_clicked: username,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.profile_username').html(data.username);
            $('.profile_age').html(data.age);
            $('.profile_points').html(data.points);

        }
    })
});
```

**view**

```
def raise_profile(request):
    username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
    if request.is_ajax():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
        profileAge = profile.age
        profileUsername = profile.username
        profilePoints = profile.points
        return JsonResponse({'age': profileAge, 'username': profileUsername, 'points': profilePoints})
```

**comment model**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
```

**comments template**

```
<h3><a class="username">{{ i.author }}</a></h3>
```

Could somebody tell me how I can change my current process so I can use ForeignKey() instead of CharField() for my username/author fields? I've been advised that using `ForeignKey()` in this situation would improve functionality.

Also here's my comment function which includes adding an `author` field (username of the person commenting, as a `CharField()`):

```
def user_comment(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text') #the comment
        id = request.POST.get('id')

        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)
            comment.save()

            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'username': username})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why play around with CharField(). One better solution would be to have author in `Comment` model as a foreign key to the `User`. Now, you are using `<a>` tag, use its `href` attribute to hold a url that points to the author's profile. Simple and clean.

For eg,

`class Comment(models.Model):
    text = field
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Now, the `<a>` can be `<a href="/url_to_user_profile/id_of_author/">Author Name<a/>`. When the user clicks on this anchor tag, fetch its href and show authors profile based on id passed.

**Edit:**

From your comment below you do not want page refresh, so your click handler would be like

```
$("a").on("click", "function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //Make an ajax call here
});
```

Comment: The "profile" isn't a seperate URL, it just brings up a little box (AJAX) on the same page with a little summary of the user, so I can't add an `<a>` tag.

Comment: But that little box is coming via ajax right? Then why not have url that will bring you that data?

Comment: Yeah but if I do that, adding a `href` tag, then It will change the page. I need to stay on the same page (no page refresh).